# JQuery Adding multiple classes to a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to obtain the next line of code using JQuery:

```
<div class="something something_else">
</div>
```

I use `$(document.createElement('div'));` to create the div, but then how do I add `something` and `something_else` to the div?

I'm sure it's something basic, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: .addClass('something something_else')

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<div/>', {"class": "something something_else" })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "something something else";
$('<div/>').addClass("something something else");
$('<div class="something something else"/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more way to do this, like:

```
$('<div/>').addClass("something something else");
$('<div class="something something else"/>');
//plain javascript
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "something something else";
```

Answer (score 2):

best way to create a new element using javascript is:

```
var newElement = $('<div></div>');
```

and then you can apply 4 this element any attribute using ***attr()*** or ***addClass()*** coomands.