# Creating HTML element with multiple classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, as you can see in the code below I want to create an HTML element, actually a `div` with `class` but since I need to create a `div` like this: `<div class="btn btn-danger">Close</div>`, this is not working for me. Here is the code:

```
close: function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                $('<div class=btn>Close</div>')
                    .appendTo('p')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.slideUp();
                    });
            }
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: $('<div class="btn">Close</div>') -> the html attributes must be used between quotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Adding multiple classes to a div tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139746/jquery-adding-multiple-classes-to-a-div-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 's the correct line:

`$('<div class="btn btn-danger">Close</div>')`

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this :

```
$(this).append($('<div />').attr({
        'id': idVariable,
        'class': classVariable
    }));
```

but now this snippet is reusable, you can put an id and any classes you want.